# Algorithm to map string to a random number in range [0,100]

Tags: c++, random, c++14, uniform-distribution

#### Requirement

Sorry it sounds like an homework assignment but I need this feature for a dll I'm implementing in our project.

1. I have an array of strings.
2. Each string is of length 16 of random chars [0-9a-z]
3. I want to map each string to a random number in range [0,100]
4. String 'X' will always be mapped to number 'Y'

#### Attempt

```
for (string strLine; std::getline(filein, strLine);)
{
    int iSum = 0;
    for (const auto& c : strLine)
        iSum += static_cast<int>(c);

    int iRand = iSum % 101;

    using namespace std;;

    fileout << strLine << "\t" << iSum << "\t" << iRand << endl;
}
```

#### Problem

I run this on a 1000 random strings. The results are not uniform. This is not a surprise since my mapping function is embarrassing.

I tried looking at [Pseudo-random number generation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) and kinda got lost.

Comment: Any good hash function would do - MurMur, City, ...

Comment: You've already got random values, in the strings themselves. Since you want each string to always map to the same value, you shouldn't introduce additional randomness. That's why a hash function is the right solution: it always maps the each input value to the same output value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use the built-in [std::hash](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/hash/)

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>

std::hash<std::string> hasher;
iRand = hasher(strLine) % 101; // iRand will be in [0,100] range
```